# How do i do master detail implementation with WPF MVVM and Entity framework

Tags: wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-4

I have four entity Customer, product, order and order details.  On my WPF window I have customer list box showing customer name and on select of customer I would like to populate the order list box which also in my window.

Since i am using MVVM, I should have two view model, one for customer and another for order, right? and i should pass the customer to orderview model so that it can populate the orderview.

How do I even pass selected customer to the order view model? I have a property named selected item  on customer., but I still dont c how shall I get that in my order view model.

**Update:**

@Craig Trombly I have created the ObservableCollection of my order entity and has property on my view model that is binding to in Xaml. I am implementing master detail behavior like on select of customer populate my order list box. For that i need to have a property on my customer view model and I am binding that property to selectedItem in the list box in my customerView Xaml. i named that property as selectedItem. however whenever i am trying to access that selected item  property from orderview model. it is not working. can you plz tell what i am doing wrong? that selectedItem property in my customer view model should set everytime I select a new item in the list on customer view. it s not doing that either.

Comment: I need to see the xaml for the this view.  Do you have everything in smaller modules?  You may have broke it down further than necessary.  Can you please post the project (even shortened down)

Comment: My email address is listed in my profile, you may want to talk this through, if you email me, i will give you my #

Comment: @Craig Trombly thank you so much. I will do that. the project i am working on right now use a different db. I will create another project with the OMS db and email the project to you.

Comment: I do not need the DB becuase i am nt trying to compile, I just want to see how you have it structured so I can help you out.

Comment: @CraigTrombly I have emailed you my code. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]The ViewModel is tied to your View (the xaml & cs), it is not around the data.

For instance, MainWindow.xaml & cs should have a MainWindowViewModel.cs

You use one ViewModel to your view.  I would suggest using the entity framework for your data.

Comment: I am using entity framework for my data. Therefore i dont have any explicit model. However my linq to entity query resides in my customerviewModel. is this wrong?

Comment: I feel that you are creating the ViewModel around your data and not necessarily to your View.  Model-View-ViewModel is a pattern that is seperate from your data model.  The entity framework is accessible to your entire project and if you need to do any custom functions (Linq) then simply add a database.cs file to your project and use that in your ViewModel.

Comment: thank you much for the info. i will implement the way you explained.

Comment: In your ViewModel, create variables for CollectionView or ObservableCollection and add your EntityDBEntities dbContent = new EntityDBEntities ();  this will allow you to get data in & out and update even.  You bind the variables to UI through your viewmodel and {Binding var_name} in your XAML

Comment: You may want to checkout from codeplex the MVVM light for VS.